# jQuery chaining val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I have a user chosen background color:

```
var _back = "#FF0000";
```

Why doesn't this set the background color of my input field:

```
$("#input").val( _back ).css("background-color",$(this).val());
```

when this does:

```
$("#input").val( _back ).css("background-color",$("#input").val());
```

It does, however if I introduce a .each()

```
$("#input").val(_back).each(function(){$(this).css("background-color",$(this).val()) })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allready have the value in a variable. just add that in the css method:

```
$("#input").val( _back ).css("background-color",  _back);
```

Another reason this would be better, is that you dont need jQuery to start the method `.val()`, which saves some overhead.

The reason it doesn't work is because `$(this)` in the css method doesnt exist (well, it does, but its not pointing to the element you want). Functions like `each` or `animate` set the `this` value, css doesnt. This probably is because there are not alot of reasons to use `this` in css

Comment: +1ed the answer earlier, though I'm not sure what do you mean by `$(this)` doesn't exist in the css method? The css method may not provide it's own context for `this` but it still exists and can be queried. `$("#input").val('test-value').css("background-color", console.log($(this)));` It won't set your background colour to anything but it will execute and log `window` (if on the top level) as `$(this)` does exist - [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5RFW/).

Comment: Yes, `this` exists, but not the way the TS expected. Some jQuery functions 'reset' the `this` to the current element (like in the each-loop). `.css()` doesn't do this, and the `this` value hasn't changed to the input, but remained in (jn this case) `window`

Comment: I suppose the `css()` method is designed like a static one, making reference to the owner of method using `this` impossible.

Comment: @Martijn Your explanatory statements are not right. The `css()` method _does_ set `this`, but will not see `$(this)...` at all, because it is evaluated before `css()` is called. To give `css()` the opportunity to influence this `this`, pass it a function to call! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663358/825924).

Answer (score 0):

Because `$(this)` refers to the function you are in, but chaining the `css()` function on the end of the `val()` function doesn't nest functions, so there is no `this` object to refer to.

You could also simplify it by writing:

```
$("#input").css("background-color", _back);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The accepted answer is a reasonable work-around, but doesn’t solve your problem statement.**

The problem in the line

```
$("#input").val( _back ).css("background-color",$(this).val());
```

is that `$(this)` is evaluated *before* `css()` is called.—And that is what always happens before you call a function: all it’s arguments will be evaluated beforehand. That `$(this)` is evaluated on the same level with the same context as `$("#input")` and both don’t know about each other.

On this line

```
$("#input").val(_back).each(function(){$(this).css("background-color",$(this).val()) })
```

both `$(this)` are part of the source code of the anonymous function you create and pass to `each()`. And `each()` calls this function itself, so it has the opportunity to set up `this`.

The “good” news is: `css()` eats functions, too. The API allows both:

```
.css( propertyName, value )
.css( propertyName, function )
```

If you feed it a function, `css()` will call that function, similar to `each()`, but only once, and use its return value.

You can fix your line with:

```
$("#input").val(_back).css("background-color", function(){return $(this).val();});
```

Note: you can not use the arrow function `() => $(this).val()` here. This is the most important difference between arrow and “normal” functions: there is no way to give arrow functions any `this`. They always take it from their lexical surrounding and this would introduce the problem we are trying to solve here...